# Apache Ignite: Thick Client Blocked Waiting For Lock On Initialization

Tags: java, ignite

I was recently trying to reproduce an issue which caused our team a production outage.

In order to reproduce the issue I rebooted both Apache Ignite cluster nodes and shortly afterwards rebooted all the services which rely on Apache Ignite.

The Apache Ignite cluster seems to have formed normally but unfortunately it seems that any service which tries to boot up and make a connection to Apache Ignite is now blocked indefinitely. Additionally, rebooting the services has no effect, they continue to get caught in some Ignite lock.

I have captured a thread dump and you can see this service's main thread is just stuck. We are using Apache Ignite 2.7.6 on Kubernetes.

> "main" - Thread t@1
> java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
> at java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
> at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:219)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:160)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:152)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.onKernalStart(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:688)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.onKernalStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:995)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1124)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2038)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1730)
> - locked <2e3b2816> (a org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1158)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:678)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:618)
> at app//org.apache.ignite.Ignition.getOrStart(Ignition.java:415)
> at app//.main(App.java:60)

If I look at the logs it appears the client is able to connect to the cluster but for some reason the main thread is still blocked?

> [03:52:55] Topology snapshot [ver=292, locNode=5b974038, servers=2, clients=60, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=358, offheap=12.0GB, heap=120.0GB]

Comment: Looks like a hanging PME. Do you have "Failed to wait for partition map exchange" message in any nodes' logs? Any exceptions prior to that message?

Comment: I took a look at the logs using Kibana and I don't see anything including that string or even "partition map". I don't see anything unusual.